# Create mysql table from PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

A user is creating a table. The user enters the number of fields that will be in the table, and a form is generated based on the number they entered. They then enter the names of the columns and the type. I then create the table based on what they entered.

I can get the arrays to populate correctly, but my error message says I have a syntax error. I'm sure I did something wrong, but I tried to add a while loop inside the query since there is no set number of variables to be entered. This is what I have. If there's a better way to do it, I'm all ears.

```
    $sql = 'CREATE TABLE $table (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
PRIMARY KEY(id), ';

        while($numDone < $totalFields){
            $sql .= $colName[$x] . ' ' . $types[$x] . ', ';
            $x++;
            $numDone++;
        }
        $sql .= ')';
    $query1 = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

**Solved
I changed the single quotes to double quotes, used the dot operator for $table, and added an if statement for the comma. It's working now.

Comment: Please post your complete error (obviously), and the `var_dump` of the `$sql`

Comment: Do you realise that creating tables on user's request is extremely unusual practice and in general being **a very bad idea**?

Comment: I understand that. I'm just putting together a data entry program to be used by one guy. I'll work on making it more secure later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You apparenty have an extra trailing comma:

```
CREATE TABLE $table (
       id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       PRIMARY KEY(id),
       col1 INT,
       col2 INT,
--             ^ here
       )
```

Comment: I wasn't sure how to get rid of that since I'm using a loop.

Comment: @user1978550: look up `implode`

Answer (score 2):

For one, this

```
'CREATE TABLE $table'
```

will NOT fill in $table, but will be LITERALLY

```
CREATE TABLE $table
```

use `"` if you want variables to be shown. You would've spotted that if you'd just echo your `$sql`. There might be more, but probably easily discoverable trough mentioned debugging...

Comment: I did echo my $sql, and everything came out as it should. I'll try the double quotes anyway.

Comment: If you did echo the `$sql`, add that to your questionk, and show us the output.

Answer (score 0):

## 1

change the single quotes (') to double quotes (") for your query.

## 2

or use dot operator (.) to append php variable.

```
$tableName = "mytable";
echo $query1 = "SELECT * FROM $tableName";
echo $query2 = 'SELECT * FROM $tableName';
```

// Output

SELECT * FROM mytable

SELECT * FROM $tableName

Answer (score 0):

You may have VARCHAR field entered without size like `fieldname VARCHAR` will return error instead it should be like `fieldname VARCHAR(100)` ? Trailing comma may also be the reason for error as Quassnoi commented.

Comment: I knew the trailing comma might be an issue, but I wasn't sure how to get rid of it. I guess some sort of if statement to make to known that it's the last one...?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get rid of the trailing slash you can also do this by using a counter.

```
$fieldsCount = count($listingFields);
foreach($listingFields as $key => $listing)
{ // create the insert statement (do not add comma at the end)
    $query .=" ".$listing[0];
    if ( $key+1 != $fieldsCount )
    {
        $query .=',';
    }
}
```